# Установка корневого сертификата УЦ с помощью PowerShell в требуемое хранилище

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

Есть корневой сертификат удостоверяющего центра (УЦ), например: C:\Cert\xxx.crt.

Требуется его установить в следующие хранилища (далее действия при ручной установке):

1. "Установить сертификат" - "Далее" - "Поместить все сертификаты в следующее хранилище" - "обзор" - "доверенные корневые центры сертификации" - "Далее" - "Готово".
2. "Установить сертификат" - "Далее" - "Поместить все сертификаты в следующее хранилище" - "обзор" - "Показать физические хранилища" - "доверенные корневые центры сертификации" - "реестр" - "Далее" - "Готово".
3. "Установить сертификат" - "Далее" - "Поместить все сертификаты в следующее хранилище" - "обзор" - "Показать физические хранилища" - "доверенные корневые центры сертификации" - "Локальный компьютер" - "Далее" - "Готово".

Как сделать эти 3 варианта скриптами на PowerShell?

Пытался сделать так:

```
$certs = New-Object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2
$path = "xxx.crt"
$password = Read-Host "Type password for PFX certificate" -AsSecureString
$flags = ???
$certs.Import($path, $password, $flags)
$store = New-Object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store ???, ???
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$store.Add($certs)
$store.Close()
```

Неправильные параметры я заменил на "???".

- Ошибка в import;
- Какие параметры должны быть в $flags?
- Какие параметры должны быть в $store?

Comment: Зачем вы работаете с .нет классами когда есть модуль PKI со всеми командлетами? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/Import-Certificate

Comment: Я очень плохо знаю PowerShell и сертификаты и их инструментарий. Нашел в интернет образец, пытался сделать по нему. Как бы Вы сделали, можете накидать пример? Вот по Вашей ссылке: как сделать импорт  с указанием физического хранилища в "реестр"?

Comment: да, по моей ссылку командлет сразу импортирует сертификат куда указано. я не уверен, но этот модуль есть вроде только с windows server 2012 r2 и выше, проверьте у себя